# How to filter web elements from the DOM which are being used on the frontend

Tags: javascript, jquery, selenium, xpath

I am trying to create utility which will generate xpath for the webelements present in the DOM.

The problem statement is that: We do not want all the elements present inside the DOM. We need to filter out all the elements which are interactable so that Xpath is created for only those elements.

Is there any way to filter out the elements present inside the DOM, while fetching the elements which using driver.findElements or is there any way I can user JQuery or JavaScript to achieve such functionality.

Comment: there are few methods available in xpath to filter stuff, but why are you trying to create a utility to generate xpath ? shouldn't it be a skill rather than a program ?

Comment: @cruisepandey ya i agree that it should be a skill. Methods to filter xpath is with respect to the selenium api or other things?